# How to install duck dns script on freebsd

Tags: dns, cron, freebsd

hi i'm wanting to install duckdns on freebsd but have been having trouble. for one thing duckdns has three scripts that might apply to my case, linux cron, linux bsd cron, and linux netcat cron. As a new linux user i'm not sure which applies to me, however i assume the netcat version doesn't apply since curl is available on freebsd.

Anyways i have error with both the scripts with both linux cron, and linux bsd cron

the linux cron script:

```
echo url="https://www.duckdns.org/update?domains=exampledomain&token=a7c4d0ad-114e-40ef-ba1d-d217904a50f2&ip=" | curl -k -o ~/duckdns/duck.log -K -
```

The error i get with the linux cron script is curl states that there is no url specified

as for the linux bsd script:

```
#!/bin/sh

DOMAINS="example"
TOKEN="feedface-dead-c0ed-babe-c0ffeec0de99"
curl_out=$( echo
url="https://www.duckdns.org/update?domains=exampledomain&token=a7c4d0ad-114e-40ef-ba1d-d217904a50f2"
| /usr/local/bin/curl --insecure --silent --config - )

if [  == "OK" ]; then
    logger -p daemon.info "duckdns update ok"
else
    logger -p daemon.err "duckdns update failed"
fi
```

I get the error:

```
./duck.sh: 7: Syntax error: "|" unexpected
./duck.sh: 5: Syntax error: Error in command substitution
```

so how can i set up duckdns with freebsd which of the two scripts do i use and how do i fix it so they work?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about the FreeBSD operating system and its utilities are off topic here and should, instead, be asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ Please delete this and ask over there. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: "Linux BSD" is a contradiction in terms; if your system is Linux, it cannot be BSD, and vice versa (though there is a very peripheral corner case where Debian used to allow you to experimentally run a BSD kernel on an otherwise Linux-based system).

Comment: `if [  == "OK" ];` is definitely a syntax error. I'm guessing the original script actually contained an unquoted variable there before the equals sign, which is an error too, but nominally syntactically valid.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried those scripts on FreeBSD from shell and the linux cron script runs correctly and writes "KO" to ~/duckdns/duck.log. Please note that `~` may not work in crontab, use full path to log file instead.

The script is somewhat messed up. Fixed it.

```
#!/bin/sh

DOMAINS="example"
TOKEN="feedface-dead-c0ed-babe-c0ffeec0de99"
curl_out=$(echo url="https://www.duckdns.org/updatedomains=exampledomain&token=a7c4d0ad-114e-40ef-ba1d-d217904a50f2" |
    /usr/local/bin/curl --insecure --silent --config - )
    
if [ "$curl_out" == "OK" ] 
then
    logger -p daemon.info "duckdns update ok"
else
    logger -p daemon.err "duckdns update failed"
fi
```

Also runs and writes `duckdns update failed` to system log.